# Plot categorical interactions in logistic regression with Odds Ratio and 95%CI with R

Tags: r, ggplot2, logistic-regression, interaction

Quick question here. I am trying to use the `interactions` package for R, to plot categorical interactions from a logistic regression model. Basically, let's say that I have a regression in which I have an interaction `factor1*factor2`, I would like to produce a plot with the OR and 95%CI of `factor2` levels across `factor1` levels, also reporting the p for interaction.

This is my current code:

```
library(interactions)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

set.seed(154)
outcome=sample(c(0,1), 1000, replace=TRUE)
set.seed(158)
factor1=sample(c("A","B"), 1000, replace=TRUE)
set.seed(1258)
factor2=sample(c("D","F"), 1000, replace=TRUE)

df <- data.frame(outcome, factor1, factor2)
df$outcome <- as.factor(df$outcome)

fit3 <- glm(outcome ~ factor1*factor2, data = df, family=binomial(link="logit"))

cat_plot(fit3, pred = factor1, modx = factor2, interval = TRUE)
```

Which produces the following outcome:
[image]

However, I was unable to add OR and 95%CI labels on top of each lines, and I was also unable to add p values for interaction. Is there a way I can do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a trade-off with ggplot wrappers like `cat_plot`. What you gain in ease-of-use, you lose in ability to customize the plot. I would tend to use vanilla ggplot in these circumstances, but in this case it's not terribly difficult to add appropriate text labels by adding these on as layers to your existing `cat_plot`

```r
library(geomtextpath)

p <- cat_plot(fit3, pred = factor1, modx = factor2, interval = TRUE)

p2o <- function(x) round(x/(1 - x), 3)

p + 
  geom_textpath(data = data.frame(factor1 = c('A', 'A', 'B', 'B'),
                                  factor2 = 'D', 
                                  outcome = c(0.625, 0.64, 0.64, 0.625)),
                aes(label = paste('Interaction p =', 
                                  scales::pvalue(summary(fit3)$coef[4, 4]))),
                color = 'black') +
  geom_text(aes(y = ymax, label = paste0("OR ", p2o(outcome), '\n(',
                                         p2o(ymin), ' - ', p2o(ymax), ')'), 
                group = factor2), 
            color = 'black', position = position_dodge(width = 0.9),
            vjust = -0.5)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your reply, very nice.
Can I ask you how did you calculate the OR to write on top of the lineplot? I saw the function "p2o", but I cant understand how'd this is supposed to give me the OR starting from the log-odds. I have edited my question to make it fully reproducible.

Comment: @userq8957289475 as far as I can tell the y axis on the plot is the probability of `outcome`, so p2o just converts probability to odds. I suppose the label should say "odds" rather than OR. To get the OR for each of A and B would require adding a label comparing D and F where factor1 is A, and another comparing D and F where factor1 is B.